# how to prove thar $|| T\circ R|| =||T|||R|||$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

Let $T\in L(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{m})$ with $n\leq m$. If $R\in L(\mathbb{R}^{n})$,  how to prove that $|| T\circ R|| =||T|||R|||$. Here i am using two facts: Polar decomposition

When i have $V,W$ Hilbert spaces and $L:V\to W$ linear application then

i) if $dim V\leq dim W$ then exist $S\in Sym (n)$ and $O\in O(V,W)$ such that $L=O\circ S$

ii) If $dim W\leq dim V$  then exist $S\in Sym (n)$ and $O\in O(V,W)$ such that $L=S\circ O^{*}$

In this case, when $L=O\circ S$ or $L=S\circ O^{*}$ then  $||L||:=|Det S|$.

My attemp , using polar decomposition for $T=O\circ S$ imply

$||T\circ R||=||O\circ S\circ R||=|det ( S\circ R)|$ because $R$ is inyective, and using that $ O\circ O^{*}=I$, and (Im not sure if) the las equality if take $ |det ( S\circ R)|=|det ( S\circ O\circ O^{*}\circ R)|$ can to help in something, or maybe take $L_1:=S\circ O$ and $L_2=O^{*}\circ R$, Can somebody help me to continued please, or give one hint, other way to prove that, tahnk you!!!

Comment: What do you mean by $\|T\|$ for $T \in L(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m)$? For almost every definition of $\|\cdot\|$, it is **not true** that $\|T\circ R\| = \|T\|\,\|R\|$ (for all $R \in L(\Bbb R^n)$). Did you mean to type
$$
\|T \circ R\| \leq \|T\|\,\|R\|
$$
instead?

Comment: well first i take the polar decomposition for $T$, and $||T||=|det S|$

Comment: I see now that you explained that in your post. Usually, people define their notation before asking the question. With the definition you give, I think the statement is correct

Comment: i will appreciate any  help, thank you Ben Grossmann

Comment: Could you please give the definition of $O(V,W)$?

Comment: well if $O:V\to W$ is linear then $O$ is orthogonal inyective if $<Ox,Oy>=<x,y>$ for all $x,y\in V$, here $V,W$ are finite hilbert spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note (or verify using the polar decomposition) that $\|M\| = \sqrt{\det(M^*\circ M)}$ for $M \in L(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m)$ (with $n \leq m$) and note that $\det(A\circ B) = \det(A) \det(B)$ for $A,B \in L(\Bbb R^n)$. With that, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\|T \circ R\|^2 &= \det([T \circ R]^* \circ [T \circ R])
\\ & = \det(R^* \circ T^* \circ T \circ R)
\\ & = \det(R^* \circ [T^* \circ T] \circ R)
\\ & = \det(R^*) \det(T^* \circ T) \det(R)
\\ & =  \det(T^* \circ T)[\det(R^*)\det(R)]
\\ & = \det(T^* \circ T) \det(R^* \circ R)  = \|T\|^2\|R\|^2. 
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $\|T\circ R\| = \|T\|\cdot \|R\|$.

---

Proof of the statement: let $M = U \circ S$ be a polar decomposition (so $U$ is orthogonal injective and $S$ is symmetric). It follows that
$$
M^* \circ M = (U \circ S)^* \circ (U \circ S) = S^* \circ U^* \circ U \circ S
= S \circ (U^* \circ U) \circ S = S^2. 
$$
It follows that $\det(M^* \circ M) = \det(S^2) = \det(S)^2$. Thus, we have
$$
\sqrt{\det(M^* \circ M)} = \sqrt{\det(S)^2} = |\det(S)| = \|M\|,
$$
which was what we wanted.

Comment: im sttil dont verify your statement but i believe, thank you so much

Comment: @weymarandres I've added a proof

Comment: oh i see, thank a lot, really thank you!!!!